# How to add progress bar with percentage while downloading multiple file at a time

Tags: android

1. I am downloading file from server. The code is bellow
2. Once i click to download i have images and sounds , and text file in server so it will fetch all the data (multiple files)
3. As my bellow code shows percentage with count dialog when downloading data but the problem is the percentage dialog shows for each and every length of data but i need the dialog to show percentage for all the content not for only one content

   ```
       private void downloadFiles(String pMain, String pFileName String pURL) {
       Log.i(TAG, "Coming to this downloadBookDetails ");
       int len;
       try {
           URL url = new URL(pURL);
           Log.i(TAG, "pDownload URL" + url);
           URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
           ucon.setReadTimeout(5000);
           ucon.setConnectTimeout(10000);
           ucon.connect();
           int lenghtOfFile = ucon.getContentLength();
           Log.i(TAG, "lenght of file" + lenghtOfFile);
           InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
           BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(is, 1024 * 5);
           File directory = new File(pMainFolder, pFileName);
           Log.i(TAG, "File Name dir" + directory);
           FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(directory);
           byte[] buff = new byte[5 * 1024];
           long total = 0;
           while ((len = inStream.read(buff)) != -1) {
               total += len;
               publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
               Log.i(TAG, "Progress: Bar with Count " + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
               outStream.write(buff, 0, len);
           }
           outStream.flush();
           outStream.close();
           inStream.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           //Add Network Error.
           Log.i(TAG, "Download Error Exception " + e.getMessage());

           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Search for DownloadManager

Answer (score 0):

did you tried this [Download multiple files with one progressbar java / Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48023733/download-multiple-files-with-one-progressbar-java-android)

I can't add a comment to Question so adding as answer....