# Progress count not shows 100%

Tags: java, android

**1.** As bellow My code I have updated .

**2.** Whenever I try to download data from server I m using progress counting dialog but when download start it shows counting percentage.

**3.** But the problem is the count shows only up to 30% when the percentage comes for 30% the dialog will be dismiss (it means all data downloaded successfully)

**4.** But I need to show the dialog up to 100% complete then it should be dismiss.. the whatever file are there is server it is around 5 to 6 file .

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BaseApplication.getInstance().getCurrentActivity());
        this.progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading Please wait.");
        this.progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        this.progressDialog.setMax(100);
        this.progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.progressDialog.show();
    }

     @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

     // Here is my downloading code  but i removed 
             DownloadData("" , "" , ""); //stuff
             }


        return true;

    }
      @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        this.progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(5);

    }

     protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

     this.progressDialog.dismiss();
      }
```

---

```
 private void downloadData(String Folder, String Name, String URL) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Coming to this downloadBookDetails ");
//        int url1 = Integer.parseInt(pDownloadURL);
        int len;
        try {


               // int urlsixe = pDownloadURL.length();
               // Log.i(TAG, "URL lenght" + urlsixe);
                URL url = new URL(URL);
                Log.i(TAG, "pDownload URL" + url);
                URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
                ucon.setReadTimeout(5000);
                ucon.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                ucon.connect();
                int lenghtOfFile = ucon.getContentLength();
                Log.i(TAG, "lenght of file" + lenghtOfFile);
                InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                Log.i(TAG, " InputStream" + is);
                BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(is, 1024 * 5);
                Log.i(TAG, " BufferedInputStream" + inStream);
                File directory = new File(pMainFolder, pFileName);
                Log.i(TAG, "File Name dir" + directory);
                FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(directory);
                byte[] buff = new byte[5 * 1024];


                long total = 0;
                while ((len = inStream.read(buff)) != -1) {
                    total += len;

                   // publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / urlsixe));
//                    Log.i(TAG, "Progress: Bar with Count " + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                    outStream.write(buff, 0, len);


                }

            publishProgress();
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
                inStream.close();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Add Network Error.
            Log.i(TAG, "Download Error Exception " + e.getMessage());

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think that this.progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(5); should not be hard-coded to 5. It should calculate the percentage base on how much of the file is downloaded.

Comment: Any reason you increment by 5?

Comment: just testing purpose i put as 5 but when i put as 1 also it will not work

Comment: What does publishProgress()? Anyway you should use percent about read bytes and length of file. Anyway you should improve robustness on input/output closing.

Comment: i tried this this Download multiple files with one progressbar java / Android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48023733/download-multiple-files-with-one-progressbar-java-android

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/

Answer (score 0):

In your Asyntask onPostExecute check max value reached or not.if its reached close the dialog

```
  protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

   if (barProgressDialog.getProgress() == barProgressDialog.getMax()) {     
    this.progressDialog.dismiss();
     }
  }
```

Comment: it not works .when i try to add ur piece of code the dialog is stoped when 50% comes..

Comment: when the count comes for 50 % compleete on that time my data downloaded successfully

Answer (score 0):

First, set the progress to 0 by using setProgress(0) in your progress bar

Secondly, you are updating your progress bar after downloading the file. It will not work as you might have expected.

Use publishProgress() inside your while loop. You are already saving the length of file at the beginning of your download method. Calculate the percentage of file downloaded by total+( len/lengthOfFile*100). Now, use this information to send update value for the percentage of the progress bar instead of hardcoding increment ProgressBy(5).

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the progress percentage to `onProgeressUpdate` through `publistProgress`

try this

```
 while ((len = inStream.read(buff)) != -1) {
                    total += len;

                   publishProgress("Downloading.. "+Name+" " + (int) ((total * 100) / inStream.read(buff))));
//                    Log.i(TAG, "Progress: Bar with Count " + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                    outStream.write(buff, 0, len);


                }

          //  publishProgress();


  @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        this.progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(values[0]);

    }
```

Comment: how can i pass. onProgeressUpdate through publistProgress

Comment: see when i add ur code ..i have 6 file in server so the progress will show percentage for each and every file download

Comment: it means when one file download successfully the dialog will appear again

Comment: but you are calling  DownloadData("..) only once

Comment: otherwise you show progress with text like."downloading file1""downloading file2 etc"

Comment: ya can u please help me how can i do this

Comment: but you are calling DownloadData("..) only once ----> in doInbakground i called methode as three times ..DownloadData("" , "" , ""); DownloadData("" , "" , ""); DownloadData("" , "" , "");  but i didnt mention

Comment: how to take refference of "Name"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185783/discussion-between-uma-achanta-and-prashant).